# In Sinatra, is it possible to save global data in memory?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm adding an API to the API server. The API server was built by somebody else based on Sinatra framework. Basically it looks like:

```
class ApiMain < Sinatra::Base
   get "/api/xx" {...}
   get "/api/yy" {...}
end
```

Now I'm adding a new API, which returns a data that is loaded from db. Calls to my new API are expected to be very frequently, but the data is not frequently updated, to reduce workload of the db, I'm thinking to cache data in memory, and only load from db once a minute. Suppose there are 1000 calls to my API every minute, this way decreases 999 times of db access.

When I read Sinatra doc, I see "For every incoming request, a new instance of your application class is created, and all handler blocks run in that scope."

I'm a pure newbie of Sinatra, I wonder if it's possible to cache data in global variable that can be shared with all request scopes? If yes, how to implement the global variable? A short sample will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe redis will do the work?

Comment: Yeah, eventually should introduce redis or memcached. But for now, we don't want to add more component.

Comment: And what about environment variables?)

Comment: I guess env var doesn't work, because the data is a hash table.

Comment: But you may use ``data.to_json`` so it becomes a string. But I understand that this is definitely not the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

One of the choices is to use `set` method, which will store data in a class variable.

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  set :cache, {}

  get "/?:word?" do
    word = params[:word]
    App.cache[word] ||= 0
    App.cache[word] += 1
    count = App.cache[word]
    "`#{word}` was called #{count} times"
  end
end
```

You should keep in mind that this approach has got many gotchas. You should care of synchronization this data with its original source. You should care not to change it accidentally as far as Ruby Hash could be mutated. You will have a copy of this data for each process, etc.

Comment: A few style notes: You're mixing classic and modular styles (http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps), and this example won't work as-is without a rackup script. `set` should be called from within a `configure` block. The cache should be accessed with `settings.cache` instead of `App.cache`. Also, if this is going to run under a multithreaded web server like Puma, I would recommend using a thread-safe Concurrent::Hash. Here's a working example: https://gist.github.com/mwpastore/dc8f39cdadac4a6e32ad

Comment: @mwp, thank you for feedback. I am not mixing styles, It is actually modular style :). I didn't put rackup file as far as it is not the point (and I don't like `run! if app_file == $0`). `configure` and `settings` are just a sugar for `yield self` and `self`, but on my taste this `cache` is not something about configuration at all. So I prefer to use idiomatic Sinatra setter `set` but not in `configure` block because I feel it semantically more correct.

Comment: sorry for being pedantic here, but I still have some concerns. For modular style you should `require 'sinatra/base'` and wrap your app in a class. For classic style you should `require 'sinatra'` and keep your app inline. The app doesn't respond to any requests as you have it written now, unless you `run App` from a separate rackup script.

Comment: @mwp, It is my old habit to require whole `sinatra` namespace instead of `sinatra/base`. I think it came from ancients times when there was no `sinatra/base` at all :). (It still works fine with `sinatra` because it requires `sinatra/base` internally)

Comment: @mwp https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/main.rb#L1, but yes, I should be more explicit. Thank you.